# ObjectInputStream throwing exception on read

Tags: java, objectinputstream

I'm having difficulty with ObjectInputStream. I wrote a simple test which fails on the read with an EOF error. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Test
{  
    @Test
    public void testObjectStreams( ) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {     
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

        String stringTest = "TEST";
        oos.writeObject( stringTest );

        oos.close();
        baos.close();

        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String hexString = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary( bytes);
        byte[] reconvertedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hexString);

        assertArrayEquals( bytes, reconvertedBytes );

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(reconvertedBytes);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);

        String readString = (String) ois.readObject();

        assertEquals( stringTest, readString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your test works for me. jdk1.6.0-35 on win7

Comment: QRF... Works for me now too, jdk1.6.0 on MacOS. The fix was in the translation as it were. If you write to the stream using writeObject(), you have to read from the stream using readObject. If you write a Boolean using writeObject(), and then try to read using readBoolean() it provides an EOF exception. Good reason not to use EOF to find the end of the stream! Also a mild reason to not use the typed methods ever. What happened here is that I simplified the test for this thread, and in so doing removed the error.